# Default value for datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can you search for dates (datetimes) that contain a default value i.e. ''.  I guess it is not:

```
select * from table where dateofbirth=''
```

All the dates seem to have a default value of '1900-01-01'.  However, there are people in my database who have a date of birth on or before this date (histroic people mainly).  Therefore I cannot do:

```
select * from table where dateofbirth='1900-01-01'
```

I know that some versions of SQL Server have a default date of: 1899-12-31.

I guess it is better to use nulls for unknown dates.  I cannot do that in this case.

I have read through lots of questions on here about finding dates using SQL but I have not found an answer to my specific question.

Comment: `''` is not a valid `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

The best you are going to get is what you listed:

```
select * from table where dateofbirth='1900-01-01'
```

As you know, the problem is that if someone was really born on 1/1/1900, you will also include them. But there's really no way for your query to know the difference.

To fix this, you would need to change what your system is using for the default value (e.g. NULL or change to datetime2 or date datatype and use 1/1/0001). Then update all your 1/1/1900 values to the new default value. Yes, this will erroneously update any existing people with 1/1/1900 birthdays, but at least it will prevent any future occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the default DateTime value as;

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)
```

And apply it to the filter as appropriate;

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE DateOfBirth = CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)
```

Or if you need to select earlier dates then;

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE DateOfBirth <= CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)
```

**[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f55d9/3)**

Comment: How come `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)` works as described, but `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, 0)` produces an error?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server terms a default value for column X is only used when a new record is first created and a value is not provided for that column. After the initial creation of the record the value is just a value, same as any other. Within a single table there is no way to distinguish between records that that hold the default value in column X because it was supplied, or because it was defaulted.

This won't help you now, but an alternative to nulls that is sometimes used is to use a 'magic value'. In the case of dates of births, the maximum datetime value of 31st December 9999 could be used to indicate an unknown value (assuming your system isn't expected to be in use in 8,000 years time :) Some people (including me) don't really approve of the use of magic values because there's no way in the database of indicating their magic status.

Rhys